# Changing attributes of a newly created feature in Python form init code

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, editing, features

- I have a layer with two attributes: "text" (string) and "int" (integer).
- I used drag'n'drop form design to have a form with just the "text" attribute in it.
- I added Python Init Code:

```
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

def on_ok(layer, feature):
    field_idx = layer.fields().indexOf("int")
    attribute_changed = layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), field_idx, 12345)
    if not attribute_changed:
        raise Exception("Attribute value could not be changed!")

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    ok_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
    ok_button.clicked.connect(partial(on_ok, layer, feature))
```

So the form does not show an input widget for the "int" field. But when pressing OK, the code should change the edited feature's "int" value to 12345.

This works if I edit existing features.

But if I create a new feature, the "int" value will be empty/NULL instead of 12345.
Any pointers on how to properly update a new feature's attribute fields, that exist on a layer, but are not shown the user with the QGIS' widgets in the attribute form?

I have already tried

```
attribute_changed = feature.setAttribute(field_idx, 12345)
```

and

```
feature[attribute_name] = 12345
```

with no success either.

In my real scenario the value would be dynamic and defined elsewhere, the `12345` is just an example.

Comment: I noticed that the both the `id(feature)` is always different when I look at it in either function which suggests the object got copied (by the `partial()` call?). The same is true for `feature.id()`. As a hack I tried using a global instead of passing the feature to `on_ok()`.

Comment: The QGIS attribute form (QgsAttributeForm) is made in such a way that only the fields that are included in the form are editable and this behavior doesn't look like it can be modified. Imo your best solution would be to attach to the signals of the QgsVectorLayer to update the value independently of the form. Which in a way is what you do when you change the value of the "int" field at the closing of the attribute form.

Comment: I don't understand. How does the form prevent other fields to be edited? Am I not side-stepping the form by using a method of the layer? Which signal would you suggest and how would I make sure to pass a value from the form (the `12345` in the example) to the layer/feature?

Comment: I mean that you can't use form functions directly from the "dialog" object if the field is removed from the form. So you have to edit directly the layer independently from any form "actions". the way @Matt does it is good (I didn't know about that use of editBuffer()) but it needs to handle update of feature too (probably depending if the id is >0 or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal solution, based on @Matt's great answer:

```
from functools import partial

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QSpinBox

def on_ok(layer, feature, spinbox):
    value = spinbox.value()
    field_idx = layer.fields().indexOf("int")
    
    feature_id = feature.id()
    if feature_id == -9223372036854775808:
        # this feature was newly added in this "form session"
        edit_buffer = layer.editBuffer()
        added_feats = edit_buffer.addedFeatures()
        # get the id of the most recently added feature in the edit buffer
        feature_id = min(list(added_feats.keys()))
    # otherwise we are looking at an existing feature, committed or not
    
    attribute_changed = layer.changeAttributeValue(feature_id, field_idx, value)
    if not attribute_changed:
        raise Exception("Attribute value could not be changed!")

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    layout = dialog.layout()
    spinbox = QSpinBox()
    layout.insertWidget(0, spinbox)

    ok_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
    ok_button.clicked.connect(partial(on_ok, layer, feature, spinbox))
```

Explanation: When a new feature is "about to be created", the form receives a blank feature with the ID `-9223372036854775808` (-2**63). In that case we have to get the actual feature's ID from the edit buffer *after* it has been created, which happens when the user OKs the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a print statement in `on_ok` to check the `feature.id()` you will probably find that it is wildly different to what you expect.

I was able to get the correct feature id by querying the `editBuffer` of the layer for the most recently added feature. While editing, features receive an incrementally decreasing negative feature id, so the most recent is the lowest value.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QPushButton
from functools import partial

def on_ok(layer, feature):
    field_idx = layer.fields().indexOf("int")
    
    print(feature.id()) # <--- not what you expect

    edit_buffer = layer.editBuffer()
    added_feats = edit_buffer.addedFeatures()

    # get the id of the most recently added feature in the edit buffer
    last_added_feat_id = min(list(added_feats.keys()))
    
    attribute_changed = layer.changeAttributeValue(last_added_feat_id, field_idx, 12345)
    if not attribute_changed:
        raise Exception("Attribute value could not be changed!")

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    ok_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
    ok_button.clicked.connect(partial(on_ok, layer, feature))
```

Comment: Nicely done for new features but `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence` on the update feature if the feature wasn't created in the edit block or would modify the wrong feature (change last added feature instead of the feature selected for update).

Comment: Good catch, but I will leave it like this for now. I have every faith that @bugmenot123 is skilled enough to add the relevant checks specific to their use case. The `editBuffer` object also has an `attributeValueChanged` signal which will emit the feature id of the edited feature.

Comment: Thank you! This would break as soon as a second feature was added before the form of the first one was closed though, right?

Comment: I just tested and this doesn't seem to be the case. I added a few features (not closing the feature form between edits) and after confirming by clicking 'OK' on all open forms, every feature received `12345` in the "int" field. It would probably require a little more robust testing, however.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I made a classical mistake of trying to make the example as small as possible. `12345` was just a fixed example number, in reality each feature would get its own value, actually defined by other code in the form init dialog code.

Comment: Indeed, I understood that from your question. But, as I have no idea how that should be calculated, I cannot say for sure whether my solution will work or fail. Are you able to test and provide feedback?

Comment: Got it work, thank you so much. I will need to revise the question and share the solution, hopefully I can do that tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks again @Matt, apparently tomorrow meant "tomonthow" ;) I added an answer now.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working :). Thanks for providing the complete solution.